# How to get path/URL without language prefix (for multilingual site)

Tags: 9, i18n-l10n

I have written a code to get the parameters (node_id, taxonomy_id) from the URL using the following code.

**Sample URL**: `/foo/bar/[nid]\/[tid]`

```
$path = \Drupal::request()->getpathInfo();
$arg = explode('/', $path);
$node_id = $arg[3]; //gives [nid]
$term_id = $arg[4]; // gives [tid]
```

This works, but when I switch to other language (say spanish), the URL becomes

```
/es/foo/bar/[nid]/[tid]
```

So obviously the code doesn't work in this case. Is there anyway to handle this?

Comment: Can you please inspect what `Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameters()` is returning you?

Comment: I think I see what you're saying, I think we can get node/taxonomy object using this.. but what about the parameter 'foo' and 'bar' how should I check them?

Comment: What's with `\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();`?

Comment: thank you @leymannx, I did learn something from you today.. and I have got the solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Here's the code to get the URL without language prefix.

```
use Drupal\Core\Url;
$current_url = Url::fromRoute('<current>');
// If we want to get the url without language prefix
$path = $current_url->getInternalPath();
$path_args = explode('/', $path);
```